# How to fix "float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp' " error?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm writing some code to predict the stock market using machine learning and deep learning techniques. But, when I try to use Linear Regression, I'm getting this error that I cannot seem to fix. 
My data is of the stocks for a certain company. The features are Date, Open, Low, High, Close, Last, Turnover, and Total Trade Quantity.

I've already looked at the similar answers for this question on stackoverflow, but the techniques they used aren't working.

```
#setting index as date
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%Y-%m-%d')
df.index = df['Date']

#sorting
data = df.sort_index(ascending=True, axis=0)

#creating a separate dataset
new_data = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(df)),columns=['Date', 
'Close'])

for i in range(0,len(data)):
    new_data['Date'][i] = data['Date'][i]
    new_data['Close'][i] = data['Close'][i]

#split into train and test data
train = df[:130]
test = df[130:]

x_train = train.drop('Close', axis=1)
y_train = train['Close']
x_test = test.drop('Close', axis=1)
y_test = test['Close']

#implement linear regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

The last line throws this error :

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not
>   'Timestamp'

Comment: try changing datatype 'timestamp' to 'string' just for experimentation purpose. also post the output for  `df.info()` so that it might clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

The index of the dataframe df is set equal to Date. Try removing it after you've done the sort_index() step.

After the sort_index step, do this:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then split the df into train-test and proceed with the Regression step.
Perhaps this can help.